# Under Input Text Box are not Copy text on Clipboard?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to copy copy to clipboard from text box using JavaScript. It works outside of `<input>....</input>`, it copies perfectly. But when clicking under `<input>....</input>` it does not work - it does not copy any text to clipBoard

[image]

How do I remove this problem?

```js
var elementsWorthCopying = document.querySelectorAll("topx .title");

var styleSheetWrapperEl = document.getElementById('topx');
styleSheetWrapperEl.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.className !== 'title') return;
  var element = e.target;
  flashElement(element);
  copyText(element);
});

function copyText(element) {
  var textToCopy = element.innerText;
  var myTemporaryInputElement = document.createElement("input");
  myTemporaryInputElement.type = "text";
  myTemporaryInputElement.value = textToCopy;
  document.body.appendChild(myTemporaryInputElement);
  myTemporaryInputElement.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  document.body.removeChild(myTemporaryInputElement);
}

function flashElement(element) {
  element.classList.add("flash");
  document.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.classList.remove("flash");
    }, 1500);
  });
}
```

```css
.btn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 500px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 2.2rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-width: 0.2rem;
  border-style: solid;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.locker {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    padding: 2px;
}
.title {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.locker .flash {
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px blue;
}
.locker .flash:after {
  content: "Text Copied!";
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 2rem);
  width: 15rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #111;
}
.title input {
    width: 99%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="locker" id="topx">

<div class="title">
<input type="text" id="black-bracket" value="Under Input Text Are Here">Outside Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When handling an `input` element, you need to access its `value` property in order to copy its content.

Please view example:

```js
var styleSheetWrapperEl = document.getElementById('topx');
styleSheetWrapperEl.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var isInput = e.target.className !== 'title';
  var element = e.target;
  flashElement(element);
  copyText(element, isInput);
});

function copyText(element, isInput) {
  // The magic happens here
  var textToCopy = isInput ? element.value : element.innerText;

  var myTemporaryInputElement = document.createElement("input");
  myTemporaryInputElement.type = "text";
  myTemporaryInputElement.value = textToCopy;
  document.body.appendChild(myTemporaryInputElement);
  myTemporaryInputElement.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  document.body.removeChild(myTemporaryInputElement);
}

function flashElement(element) {
  element.classList.add("flash");
  document.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.classList.remove("flash");
    }, 1500);
  });
}
```

```css
.btn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 500px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 2.2rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-width: 0.2rem;
  border-style: solid;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.locker {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    padding: 2px;
}
.title {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.locker .flash {
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px blue;
}
.locker .flash:after {
  content: "Text Copied!";
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 2rem);
  width: 15rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #111;
}
.title input {
    width: 99%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="locker" id="topx">

<div class="title">
<input type="text" id="black-bracket" value="Under Input Text Are Here">Outside Text
</div>
```